# Pandas Data Merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, merging-data

I am new to pandas. Is there any way i can merge this 2 dataframes into following result

DataFrame1:-

```
|-------------|---------|----------------------|-------|  
|Test Case    | SubTest | App                  | Count |  
| geekebench5 | OpenCL  | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0   |  
| geekebench5 | OpenCL  | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0   |  
| geekebench5 | Vulkan  | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0   |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 2.0   |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0   |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0   |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0   |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | Process              | 1.0   |  
|-------------|---------|----------------------|-------|
```

DataFrame2:-

```
|-------------|---------|----------------------|-------|  
|Test Case    | SubTest | App                  | Count |  
| geekebench5 | OpenCL  | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 2.0   |  
| geekebench5 | Vulkan  | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0   |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 2.0   |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0   |  
|-------------|---------|----------------------|-------|
```

DataFrame Result:-

```
|-------------|---------|----------------------|---------|---------|  
|Test Case    | SubTest | App                  | Count_x | Count_y |  
| geekebench5 | OpenCL  | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0     |  2.0    |  
| geekebench5 | OpenCL  | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0     |  NaN    |  
| geekebench5 | Vulkan  | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0     |  1.0    |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 2.0     |  2.0    |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0     |  1.0    |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0     |  NaN    |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | geekbench_x86_64.exe | 1.0     |  NaN    |  
| geekebench5 | cpu     | Process              | 1.0     |  NaN    |  
|-------------|---------|----------------------|---------|---------|
```

Merging using left operation does not help. No of row count increases and it instead of NaN, it enters the previous row value

Comment: you meant left_join it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: probably anwsers many more questions in the future, nice post